# RxJava "serialize" method use cases

Tags: java, rx-java2

I want to know cases in which we need to "serialize" observable, its necessary. I mean cases in which "onNext" method will get called concurrently instead of one after another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Originally, `serialize()` was introduced to fix some badly behaving custom `Observable`s from the consumer's end instead of making the author fix his `create()`-ion in 1.x. As the enforcing of the `Observable` protocol became more prominent, there was less need for the operator in practice. It still ended up in v2 just in case and for "nostalgic reasons". Note that its sibling, `Subject.toSerialized()` is completely legitimate and is there to serialize access to a `Subject` in case it is driven from multiple threads.

Comment: So you mean there is no use of serialize in v2.

Comment: I don't think there is use for it.

Comment: Hi akarnokd, in cases where we use flatMap and subscribeOn different threads. In that case is it guaranteed that onNext will get sequentially called. Or is it possible that it may get concurrently called.

Comment: Concurrent calls to onNext is forbidden and the RxJava operators are written as such to ensure proper sequential calls. Anything else is a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your help.